# Make the first image the post thumbnail without setting it as the featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to set a post thumbnail without setting it as featured image. My website is https://www.shockinpoop.com/. If you may, please open any article and you will see that the featured image is displaying twice. One before the post title and one immediately after it. But what I want is to make it appear like this https://www.shockinpoop.com/life-2/tyler-durden-was-right-all-along/. I want to the image to appear **after** the title like in this article. The only way I can do this is by removing the featured image but that removes the post thumbnail from my homepage. Also, my theme automatically attaches the image to a post when i use 'add media' button to insert an image within the post. This leads to the image appearing twice. I am extremely sorry if I am not able to explain myself. I just want the first image of the post to be used as post thumbnail, without using it as the featured image. I think this can be done by php although I am not sure. Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you. Here is the complete code of single.php

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    /**
     * Allow for changing the template partial.
     *
     * @since 1.2.3.
     *
     * @param string     $type    The default template type to use.
     * @param WP_Post    $post    The post object for the current post.
     */
    $template_type = apply_filters( 'make_template_content_single', 'single', $post );
    get_template_part( 'partials/content', $template_type );
    ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/nav', 'post' ); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'comments' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: right now i am not able to open any article. It redirects to the url of featured image .  You need to post the code of single.php

Comment: Is there any chance I can just hide featured image from appearing only on single post page?

Comment: Second featured image is also coming automatically or are you adding it from the backend? And which theme you are you using?

Comment: I am using the 'Make' theme by theme foundry. Is there a code for hiding image from single post page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the css hide one of the images for now until you figure it out. Coz nothing is clear from above code

Add these lines to your style.css

```
.entry-header figure{
  display: none !important;
}
```

refresh your cache and you will the problem fixed

Comment: Glad could help you out .